# How to access NVRAM and DPRAM in Linux userspace?

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, ram

We are going to add NVRAM and DPRAM in our custom board where both of them will be mapped in system memory map. I am not getting a clue that whether these devices have some generic drivers in Linux kernel so that they appear as devices in `dev` directory (e.g. `/dev/nvram` or `/dev/dpram`) or do I need to access them via `/dev/mem` using `mmap`?

Answer (score 2):

Since you said "custom board", you should have specified whether this is x86 architecture, some variety of ARM, or something else.

Nevertheless, unless the kernel receives some information telling it where the NVRAM and DPRAM are located in the system memory map, it will have no knowledge of them. This information can come from the firmware (x86: e820 mechanism, UEFI, ACPI and/or other PnP mechanisms) or from the bootloader (ARM: ATAGS or [the device tree blob](https://events.static.linuxfound.org/sites/events/files/slides/petazzoni-device-tree-dummies.pdf)).

You should also see if the MTD drivers are applicable to your needs: in particular, it seems to me that the `CONFIG_MTD_PHRAM` kernel driver (or its predecessor, the `slram` driver) might be useful to you.

[This question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15610570/9197000) might also have some information useful to you. Basically, you might want to register your NVRAM and DPRAM as platform devices, if you cannot meaningfully include them into the device tree or other memory map that is handed over from the firmware/bootloader to the kernel.

Comment: Thanks, we are using PowerPC and are going to tell the kernel about NVRAM and DPRAM via device tree. Should I add some driver name in compatible property of these devices in device tree node? Or they can be directly accessed via /dev/mem now?